# How to find the two boundary edges of a boundary vertex in the half edge data structure?

Tags: data-structures, graphics, mesh

[image]

I can find the most counter clock wise by simply doing:

```
while (edge && edge->twin()) {
  edge = edge->twin()->next()
}
```

but I'm not able to find a way by traversing the edges to get the second edge, basically find the other extreme (clock wise edge)

ref: http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `edge->prev()->twin()` exists. If it does, go there and iterate. If not, `edge->prev()` is your boundary half edge.

Comment: Is that a question or a statement? If you don't have previous pointers, you have to follow the next pointers until `->next() == e`.

Answer (score 1):

For these situations you can use a boundary face, a dummy face that is not rendered. The edges of that face form a loop, which are the twins  of the edges that form the boundary loop of the mesh. This allows you to traverse pair->next as usual (check all edges/faces connected to a vertex as well as all neighboring vertices), where every edge that has a boundary face is obviously a boundary.